# How to automatically delete empty UITableView cells if they contain no data?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

**EDIT 1: Object declaration (go to the bottom of the post)**

I'm loading data from a JSON (downloaded through my API) and for some reason, for the past few days, I've had cells appear as empty, in between perfectly well-built cells with actual data. How can I make those empty cells automatically disappear ? (so there is no gap in between cells) ?

Here is my code where I create objects from the JSON, and my data source code:

Objects code:

```
  func populateCurrentIssue() {
    if populatingCurrentIssue {
        return
    }

    populatingCurrentIssue = true

    self.cellLoadingIndicator.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
    self.cellLoadingIndicator.startAnimating()

    Alamofire.request(GWNetworking.Router.Issue).responseJSON() { response in
        if let JSON = response.result.value {

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)) {

                var nodeIDArray : [Int]

                if (JSON .isKindOfClass(NSDictionary)) {

                    for node in JSON as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {

                        let nodeIDValue = node.0
                        var lastItem : Int = 0

                        if let issueElement : IssueElement = IssueElement(title: "Could not retrieve title", nodeID: 0, timeStamp: 0, imageURL: "init", author: "Author not found", issueNumber: "Issue # error", volumeNumber: "Volume # error", articleContent: "Could not retrieve article content", coverImageInteger: "init", coverImage: UIImage()) {

                            issueElement.title = node.1["title"] as! String
                            issueElement.nodeID = Int(nodeIDValue)!

                            let timeStampString = node.1["revision_timestamp"] as! String
                            issueElement.timeStamp = Int(timeStampString)!

                            issueElement.imageURL = String(node.1["image_url"])

                            if let author = node.1["author"] as? String {
                                issueElement.author = author
                            }

                            issueElement.volumeNumber = String(node.1["volume_int"])

                            if let articleContent = node.1["html_content"] as? String {
                                issueElement.articleContent = articleContent
                            }

                            issueElement.coverImageInteger = String(node.1["cover_image"]) // addition specific to the Current Issue View Controller

                            lastItem = self.currentIssueObjects.count

                            print(issueElement.nodeID)

                            self.currentIssueObjects.addObject(issueElement)


                            let timestampSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "timeStamp", ascending: false)
                            self.currentIssueObjects.sortUsingDescriptors([timestampSortDescriptor])



                            let coverImageSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "coverImageInteger", ascending: false)
                            self.currentIssueObjects.sortUsingDescriptors([coverImageSortDescriptor])

                            print(self.currentIssueObjects)

                            let indexPaths = (lastItem..<self.currentIssueObjects.count).map {
                                NSIndexPath(forItem: $0, inSection: 0) }
                            }
                        }

                    }

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    self.currentIssueTableView.reloadData()

                    self.cellLoadingIndicator.stopAnimating()
                    self.cellLoadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true

                }

            }

        }

        self.populatingCurrentIssue = false
}
```

}

Data source code:

```
  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell {

    let row = indexPath.row

    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CurrentIssueArticlesTableCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as? CurrentIssueArticlesTableViewCell else {

        print ("error: currentIssueTableView cell is not of class CurrentIssueArticlesTableViewCell, we will use EditorialsTableViewCell instead")
        return tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CurrentIssueArticlesTableCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! EditorialsTableViewCell
    }



    let currentIssueObject = currentIssueObjects.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! IssueElement

        let title = currentIssueObject.title ?? ""

        let timeStampDateObject = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: NSTimeInterval(currentIssueObject.timeStamp))
        let timeStampDateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(timeStampDateObject) ?? "Date unknown"



    if let author = currentIssueObject.author {

        cell.currentIssueArticlesAuthorLabel!.font = UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleSubheadline)
        cell.currentIssueArticlesAuthorLabel!.text = author

    } else {
    }


        let issueNumber = currentIssueObject.issueNumber ?? ""
        let volumeNumber = currentIssueObject.volumeNumber ?? ""

        let articleContent = currentIssueObject.articleContent ?? ""

        let nodeID = currentIssueObject.nodeID ?? 0

        cell.currentIssueArticlesHeadlineLabel.font = UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleHeadline)
        cell.currentIssueArticlesHeadlineLabel.text = title



        cell.currentIssueArticlesPublishDateLabel.font = UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleSubheadline)
        cell.currentIssueArticlesPublishDateLabel.text = timeStampDateString

        if row == 0 {

            cell.userInteractionEnabled = false

            let imageURL = (currentIssueObjects.objectAtIndex(row) as! IssueElement).imageURL

            cell.currentIssueArticlesHeadlineLabel.textColor = UIColor.clearColor()
            cell.currentIssueArticlesAuthorLabel.textColor = UIColor.clearColor()
            cell.currentIssueArticlesPublishDateLabel.textColor = UIColor.clearColor()

            cell.request?.cancel()

            if let image = self.imageCache.objectForKey(imageURL!) as? UIImage {
                cell.currentIssueArticlesBackgroundImageView.image = image
            } else {
                cell.currentIssueArticlesBackgroundImageView.image = UIImage(named: "reveal Image")
                cell.request = Alamofire.request(.GET, imageURL!).responseImage() { response in
                    if response.result.error == nil && response.result.value != nil {

                        self.imageCache.setObject(response.result.value!, forKey: response.request!.URLString)

                        cell.currentIssueArticlesBackgroundImageView.image = response.result.value
                    } else {

                    }

                }
            }


        }

        else {



        }

    if (cell.currentIssueArticlesAuthorLabel == nil) {
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
    }

    return cell
}
```

**EDIT 1: Object declaration**

```
class IssueElement: NSObject {

var title: String           // title
var nodeID: Int             // nid
var timeStamp: Int          // revision_timestamp
var imageURL: String?      // image_url
var author: String?          // author

var issueNumber: String     // issue_int
var volumeNumber: String    // volume_int

var articleContent: String // html_content

var coverImageInteger: String // Variable that indicates whether this is the cover page or not (1 for cover, 0 for everything else)

var coverImage: UIImage

init(title: String, nodeID: Int, timeStamp: Int, imageURL: String?, author: String, issueNumber: String, volumeNumber: String, articleContent: String, coverImageInteger: String, coverImage: UIImage) {
    self.title = title
    self.nodeID = nodeID
    self.timeStamp = timeStamp
    self.imageURL = imageURL
    self.author = author
    self.issueNumber = issueNumber
    self.volumeNumber = volumeNumber
    self.articleContent = articleContent
    self.coverImageInteger = coverImageInteger
    self.coverImage = coverImage
}

override func isEqual(object: AnyObject!) -> Bool {
    return (object as! IssueElement).nodeID == self.nodeID
}

override var hash: Int {
    return (self as IssueElement).nodeID
}

}
```

Comment: Can't you validate the issueElement before adding it to the currentIssueObjects?

Answer (score 1):

Actually you don't want to do that because there will be additional problems on the way. For example, the simplest way to edit data in the cell is to link your cell's indexPath.row to your dataSource (e.g., the second cell is linked to the second element in your dataSource, third to the third and so on). If you filtering your cells and not your data, you'll break this logic.

So, the best way to do that is to filter your data, just remove empty elements before adding them to UITableView.

Comment: How would I do that ?

Comment: How do I create my NSPredicate ?

Comment: why don't you just check your issueElement before adding it to self.currentIssueObjects?

something like:

`if issueElement.title != "" {self.currentIssueObjects.addObject(issueElement)}`

Comment: I am still getting blank cells. Perhaps the values are there but it is just not displaying them properly ?

Comment: I've noticed that sometimes, I get no "author" value or no "articleContent" value from my API because the JSON it's sending me does not contain anything for those variables (for some articles). If I say " != nil", it gives me an error saying I can't use "nil" to compare a String to an AnyObject.

Comment: hmmm, maybe it's not "" but "    ", for example. it will appear as empty string but it's not empty per se. try trim the title (remove unused spaces) before the check.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Lithium's initial analysis.  Filter your data first before even adding it to the Array.  If the data is a string, then maybe try a character count validation before adding to the array, like so:

```
if issueElement.characters.count > 0 { //Add to Array... }
```

Comment: The data is an NSObject which is declared as seen in the edit I just made to my initial post (at the very bottom)

Comment: perhaps this would work ? "if issueElement.articleContent.characters.count > 0 { // add to array}

Comment: and if the condition isn't satisfied, don't do anything ?

Comment: Correct, cos you want to ignore it anyway, so don't do anything.

Comment: I just tried that and I'm still getting empty cells. Help ?

Comment: If it's not working, my best advice will be to start putting log statements everywhere.  Put log statements when you get your JSON response, during processing and after...as well as while adding to array....print the log output to console and compare values and counts of everything to make sure something funky isn't going on somewhere that is hard to catch with the naked eye.

Comment: I'm actually using 40 as a minimum, not 0, because my initial value is "Could not retrieve article content" has 34 characters (including spaces). I'm gonna look at this more closely and get back to you.

Comment: Well that could be the problem then if you are assigning values that define errors or null...It will affect checking if the object is nil or count > 0 in this case since it never will be the case, so yeah, you will need to dig into the code.